# HTML Dropdowns not properly working

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been working on this html document and I've tried to add a dropdown menu that you can choose between Australia and New Zealand and the corresponding states appear in the 'Choose States' dropdown.

```
    <div id="mydiv2">
<section>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<form name="myFirstForm" autocomplete="on">
<p>
<meter min="0" low="20" high="80" optimum="90" max="100"
value="0">Space left: </meter> 0%
</p>
<fieldset style =" margin-left:-20px; padding-top: 0.35em; padding-bottom: 
0.625em; padding-left: 0.75em;">
<p>
<meter min="0" low="20" high="80" optimum="90" max="100"
value="0">Space left: </meter> 0%
</p>
<legend> Register New User</legend>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter a new username" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}" required+"true" onblur="return validateErrors('username','usernameError')" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <span id="usernameError" style="display: none;"></span>
 <script>
 if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
 document.getElementById("username").focus();
 }
 </script>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" required pattern="[A-Z]{3}-[a-z]{3}" title="###-
### with 3 capitals followed by a - and 3 lower case letters" placeholder="6     digits or more" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 </fieldset >
 <fieldset style =" margin-left:-20px; padding-top: 0.35em; padding-bottom: 0.625em; padding-left: 0.75em;">
 <legend> Personal Details</legend>
 <legend></legend> 
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Name: <input type="text" name="Name"
autofocus="autofocus"  required="true" placeholder="first and last name" title="Must contain no numbers"  /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Address: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" placeholder="street number and name" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Suburb: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" placeholder="suburb" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>City: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" 
  placeholder="city" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 </br>


Select Country: <select id="country" name ="country"></select> <br/><br/>
Select State: <select name ="state" id ="state"></select>  <br/>

 <script language="javascript">
 populateCountries("country", "state"); // first parameter is id of country 
 drop-down and second parameter is id of state drop-down
 populateCountries("country2");
 populateCountries("country2");
 </script>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Postcode: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" 
 title="Must be 4 numbers" placeholder="0000" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Email: <input type="text" name="address" title="Must contain a @ and a ." placeholder="me@example.com"  required="true" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Phone: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" title="Must be 10 digits" placeholder="(00)-000-0000" /> </label></p>
</div>
<div id="mydiv">
<p><label>Website: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" title="Must contain a www and a ." placeholder="https://www.example.com.au" />     
</label></p>
</div>
<div id="mydiv">
<p><label>Age: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" title="Must be numeric" placeholder="" /> </label></p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style ="background-color:#4682b4; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 
800px; padding-top: 0.35em; padding-bottom: 0.625em; padding-left: 
0.75em;width:100%;">
<p>Spam Check</p>
<p><label>What colour is black?(Choose a colour)<input type="color" 
name="carcolor" /></label></p>
<script>
function checkRegistration(){
if(!form_valid){
    alert('Given data is not correct');
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Form3.html">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Continue">
</FORM>
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

However the problem I have encountered is that the dropdown for the dynamic states and countries simply isn't working and I've tried almost everything.

```
var country_arr = new Array("Australia","New Zealand");
// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Australian Capital Territory|New South Wales|Northern Territory|Queensland|South Australia|Tasmania|Victoria|Western Australia";
s_a[2]="Akaroa|Amuri|Ashburton|Bay of Islands|Bruce|Buller|Chatham Islands|Cheviot|Clifton|Clutha|Cook|Dannevirke|Egmont|Eketahuna|Ellesmere|Eltham|Eyre|Featherston|Franklin|Golden Bay|Great Barrier Island|Grey|Hauraki Plains|Hawera|Hawke's Bay|Heathcote|Hikurangi|Hobson|Hokianga|Horowhenua|Hurunui|Hutt|Inangahua|Inglewood|Kaikoura|Kairanga|Kiwitea|Lake|Mackenzie|Malvern|Manaia|Manawatu|Mangonui|Maniototo|Marlborough|Masterton|Matamata|Mount Herbert|Ohinemuri|Opotiki|Oroua|Otamatea|Otorohanga|Oxford|Pahiatua|Paparua|Patea|Piako|Pohangina|Raglan|Rangiora|Rangitikei|Rodney|Rotorua|Runanga|Saint Kilda|Silverpeaks|Southland|Stewart Island|Stratford|Strathallan|Taranaki|Taumarunui|Taupo|Tauranga|Thames-Coromandel|Tuapeka|Vincent|Waiapu|Waiheke|Waihemo|Waikato|Waikohu|Waimairi|Waimarino|Waimate|Waimate West|Waimea|Waipa|Waipawa|Waipukurau|Wairarapa South|Wairewa|Wairoa|Waitaki|Waitomo|Waitotara|Wallace|Wanganui|Waverley|Westland|Whakatane|Whangarei|Whangaroa|Woodville";



function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){

var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId 
).selectedIndex;

var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );

stateElement.length=0;  // Fixed by Julian Woods
stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
    stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new 
Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
}
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId){
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts 
<option> tags
var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
countryElement.length=0;
countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','-1');
countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
    countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
}

// Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

if( stateElementId ){
    countryElement.onchange = function(){
        populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId );
    };
}
}
function checkSubmit()
{
if (all validations are ok)
    {
        return true;
        }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

No matter what I try the dropdown just won't work. If anyone could point out where I've gone wrong, I would be very appreciative.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you you're inline JS is executing before the Javascript in the separate file. How are you referencing the external Javascript?

P.S. You should be avoiding inline JavaScript and instead using event listenters. Here is a working fiddle of your exact code, with the inline JavaScript extracted to the external file.

http://jsfiddle.net/6kx9um8o/

```js
var country_arr = new Array("Australia", "New Zealand");
// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Australian Capital Territory|New South Wales|Northern Territory|Queensland|South Australia|Tasmania|Victoria|Western Australia";
s_a[2] = "Akaroa|Amuri|Ashburton|Bay of Islands|Bruce|Buller|Chatham Islands|Cheviot|Clifton|Clutha|Cook|Dannevirke|Egmont|Eketahuna|Ellesmere|Eltham|Eyre|Featherston|Franklin|Golden Bay|Great Barrier Island|Grey|Hauraki Plains|Hawera|Hawke's Bay|Heathcote|Hikurangi|Hobson|Hokianga|Horowhenua|Hurunui|Hutt|Inangahua|Inglewood|Kaikoura|Kairanga|Kiwitea|Lake|Mackenzie|Malvern|Manaia|Manawatu|Mangonui|Maniototo|Marlborough|Masterton|Matamata|Mount Herbert|Ohinemuri|Opotiki|Oroua|Otamatea|Otorohanga|Oxford|Pahiatua|Paparua|Patea|Piako|Pohangina|Raglan|Rangiora|Rangitikei|Rodney|Rotorua|Runanga|Saint Kilda|Silverpeaks|Southland|Stewart Island|Stratford|Strathallan|Taranaki|Taumarunui|Taupo|Tauranga|Thames-Coromandel|Tuapeka|Vincent|Waiapu|Waiheke|Waihemo|Waikato|Waikohu|Waimairi|Waimarino|Waimate|Waimate West|Waimea|Waipa|Waipawa|Waipukurau|Wairarapa South|Wairewa|Wairoa|Waitaki|Waitomo|Waitotara|Wallace|Wanganui|Waverley|Westland|Whakatane|Whangarei|Whangaroa|Woodville";


function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new
        Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts 
    //<option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function() {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}

function checkSubmit() {
    if (true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }


 populateCountries("country", "state"); // first parameter is id of country 
 //drop-down and second parameter is id of state drop-down
 populateCountries("country2");
 populateCountries("country2");
```

```html
  <div id="mydiv2">
<section>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<form name="myFirstForm" autocomplete="on">
<p>
<meter min="0" low="20" high="80" optimum="90" max="100"
value="0">Space left: </meter> 0%
</p>
<fieldset style =" margin-left:-20px; padding-top: 0.35em; padding-bottom: 
0.625em; padding-left: 0.75em;">
<p>
<meter min="0" low="20" high="80" optimum="90" max="100"
value="0">Space left: </meter> 0%
</p>
<legend> Register New User</legend>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter a new username" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}" required+"true" onblur="return validateErrors('username','usernameError')" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <span id="usernameError" style="display: none;"></span>
 <script>
 if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
 document.getElementById("username").focus();
 }
 </script>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" required pattern="[A-Z]{3}-[a-z]{3}" title="###-
### with 3 capitals followed by a - and 3 lower case letters" placeholder="6     digits or more" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 </fieldset >
 <fieldset style =" margin-left:-20px; padding-top: 0.35em; padding-bottom: 0.625em; padding-left: 0.75em;">
 <legend> Personal Details</legend>
 <legend></legend> 
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Name: <input type="text" name="Name"
autofocus="autofocus"  required="true" placeholder="first and last name" title="Must contain no numbers"  /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Address: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" placeholder="street number and name" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Suburb: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" placeholder="suburb" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>City: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" 
  placeholder="city" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 </br>


Select Country: <select id="country" name ="country"></select> <br/><br/>
Select State: <select name ="state" id ="state"></select>  <br/>

 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Postcode: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" 
 title="Must be 4 numbers" placeholder="0000" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Email: <input type="text" name="address" title="Must contain a @ and a ." placeholder="me@example.com"  required="true" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" /> </label></p>
 </div>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <p><label>Phone: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" title="Must be 10 digits" placeholder="(00)-000-0000" /> </label></p>
</div>
<div id="mydiv">
<p><label>Website: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" title="Must contain a www and a ." placeholder="https://www.example.com.au" />     
</label></p>
</div>
<div id="mydiv">
<p><label>Age: <input type="text" name="address" required="true" title="Must be numeric" placeholder="" /> </label></p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style ="background-color:#4682b4; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 
800px; padding-top: 0.35em; padding-bottom: 0.625em; padding-left: 
0.75em;width:100%;">
<p>Spam Check</p>
<p><label>What colour is black?(Choose a colour)<input type="color" 
name="carcolor" /></label></p>
<script>
function checkRegistration(){
if(!form_valid){
    alert('Given data is not correct');
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Form3.html">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Continue">
```